# How to abind plans of different dimensions into an array?

Tags: arrays, r

I have an algorithm which create new data based on the merger of existing data. I would like to have the original and new data into an array but their dimensions differ: the original data's dimensions is `c(,2,1)` when the new data is `c(,2,2)` or even larger in the 3rd dimension.

I have tried to abind but it does not work

```
a = matrix(c(50,70), ncol = 2)
b = matrix(c(45,85), ncol = 2)
c = matrix(c(20,35), ncol = 2)

df =array(c(a, b,c), dim = c(3,2,1))

new.pairs = NULL
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
   for (j in (1+i):nrow(df)) {
      l = ConvexUnion.input(df[i,],df[j,])
   }
   new.pairs = aperm(abind(new.pairs,l,along = 3), c(3,2,1))
}
```

I receive the following error message:
`Error in df[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Do you know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `df` is a 3D array. You only supply two dimensions when subsetting it.

Comment: Indeed, but sometimes the result of the `ConvexUnion` function is a `c(1,2)` vector, sometimes it is `c(2,2)`. I would like to `abind` them on the third dimension but R asks me that they have all the same number of rows. Do you know what is to do?